# Visit and exit an array

Tags: code-golf, number, array, subsequence

### Challenge:

#### Input:

- An integer `n` (`> 0`)
- An integer-array `a` of size `> 0` (which contains positive and negative values, but no zeroes)

#### Output:

1. First output the first `n` items
2. Then take the last item you've outputted (let's call it `e`), and go `e` steps forward if `e` is positive, or `abs(e)` steps backwards if `e` is negative. And from that position, output `abs(e)` items (again either going forward / backwards depending on positive / negative).
3. Continue the process until you've either:

   - Outputted every distinct value of the array
   - Output one of the items at least `n` times

#### Example 1:

```
n = 3   
a = [2, 6, 9, 2, -4, -1, 3, 5, -7, 3, -2, 2, 2, 3]
     ^  ^  ^  ^   ^   ^  ^  ^   ^  ^   ^  ^  ^  ^
     A  B  C  D   E   F  G  H   I  J   K  L  M  N   ← Added as clarification
```

**Step 1:**
- Starting position `A`, `n=3`
- Output line 1: `2, 6, 9` (`A-C`)
- `e = 9` (`C`)
- Distinct values already visited: `2, 6, 9`
- Distinct values left to visit: `-7, -4, -1, -2, 3, 5`
- Amount of times we've visited the items: `A=1, B=1, C=1`

**Step 2:**
- Starting position `L` (9 steps forward from position `C`), `e=9`
- Output line 2: `2, 2, 3, 2, 6, 9, 2, -4, -1` (`L-N` + `A-F`)
- `e = -1` (`F`)
- Distinct values already visited: `-4, -1, 2, 3, 6, 9`
- Distinct values left to visit: `-7, -2, 5`
- Amount of times we've visited the items: `A=2, B=2, C=2, D=1, E=1, F=1, L=1, M=1, N=1`

**Step 3:**
- Starting position `E` (1 step backwards from position `F`), `e=-1`
- Output line 3: `-4` (`E`)
- `e = -4` (`E`)
- Distinct values already visited: `-4, -1, 2, 3, 6, 9`
- Distinct values left to visit: `-7, -2, 5`
- Amount of times we've visited the items: `A=2, B=2, C=2, D=1, E=2, F=1, L=1, M=1, N=1`

**Step 4:**
- Starting position `A` (4 steps backwards from position `E`), `e=-4`
- Output line 4: `2, 3, 2, 2` (`A` + `N-L`)
- `e = 2` (`L`)
- Distinct values already visited: `-4, -1, 2, 3, 6, 9`
- Distinct values left to visit: `-7, -2, 5`
- Amount of times we've visited the items: `A=3, B=2, C=2, D=1, E=2, F=1, L=2, M=2, N=2`

We've now visited `A` `n (3)` amount of times, so we stop.

#### Example 2:

```
n = 2
a = [2, 3, 2]
     ^  ^  ^
     A  B  C   ← Added as clarification
```

**Step 1:**
- Starting position `A`, `n=2`
- Output line 1: `2, 3` (`A-B`)
- `e = 3` (`B`)
- Distinct values already visited: `2, 3`
- Distinct values left to visit: none
- Amount of times we've visited the items: `A=1, B=1`

We've already outputted all distinct values, so we stop.

### Challenge rules:

- Input and output are flexible. Input can be an array/list of integers, string with delimiter, etc. Output can be to STDOUT, can be a 2D integer array/list, a string, etc.
- As you may have noticed from the test cases, you wrap around the array if you're out of bounds.
- The input `n` can also be larger than the size of `a` (i.e. `n = 5, a = [2, 3, 4]` will have an output of `2, 3, 4, 2, 3`, and will stop there since we've outputted all distinct values already).
- Input array can contain any reasonable integer (including those larger than the array-size) excluding `0`.
- If the input for `n` is 1, it means the output will always be just the first item.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

### Test cases:

```
Input: 3, [2, 6, 9, 2, -4, -1, 3, 5, -7, 3, -2, 2, 2, 3]
Output: [[2, 6, 9], [2, 2, 3, 2, 6, 9, 2, -4, -1], [-4], [2, 3, 2, 2]]

Input: 2, [2, 3, 2]
Output: [[2, 3]]

Input: 5, [2, 3, 4]
Output: [[2, 3, 4, 2, 3]]

Input: 1, [2, 1, -3]
Output: [[2]]

Input: 2, [1, 1, 2, -3]
Output: [[1, 1], [2], [1, 1]]

Input: 17, [1, 4, 9]
Output: [[1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4]]

Input: 2, [1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 6, -5, 4, -3, 2, -1, 1, 1, 1]
Output: [[1, -2], [1, 1], [1]]

Input: 4, [1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 6, -5, 4, -3, 2, -1, 1, 1, 1]
Output: [[1, -2, 3, -4], [1, 1, 1, -1], [2], [1, 1], [1], [1], [-2], [1, 1], [1]]

Input: 3, [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
Output: [[-1, 1, 2], [4, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, -1], [13], [12, 13, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

Input: 5, [5, 2, -3, 7, -3, 2, -4, 4, 4, 4]
Output: [[5, 2, -3, 7, -3], [2, 5, 4], [7, -3, 2, -4]]

Input: 2, [7, 24, 11]
Output: [[7, 24], [24, 11, 7, 24, 11, 7, 24, 11, 7, 24, 11, 7, 24, 11, 7, 24, 11, 7, 24, 11, 7, 24, 11, 7]]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>149</s> 140 bytes

```python
n,a=input()
l=len(a)
s=set(a)
i=0
v=[n]*l
while min(v)and s:
 for x in range(i,i+n,n>0 or-1):v[x%l]-=1;n=a[x%l];s-={n};print n,
 i=x+n;print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU/RboMwDHzPV1hIU6GNJRKgXYuyx/5Emwe0sTUScytgHdO0b2eJ0/UDJiVwtu/iu8vXeDqTnvcmSZKZZGMcXT7GNBOd6VpKm0wMZmjHAJzJxdUcyC478XlyXQvvjtJr1tALDDsBr@ceJnAEfUNvbeqkW5GkpxzOPapsdz1MD51Fo2oyDeN6QPNNP/WldzQCSQHOTCuK9ewNiXZqn9P9KuHO4ngkRPTfRZ1kS6XmQsJBS1hL2ErwAEt/lQTfrzzaMELNM38KK3RU@La2oroXpRUqFv6HN57iSseG2sSO37C9jzGqw9qwb81WsGIWFlEbXwnHivJ/shAT724K5lUs8qYeObzK/Q2UEKGI0aqbeab9vVuyuuTIIYUf6TJo7S8)

---

- -9 bytes, thanks to Bubbler

Comment: Count down from `n` instead of counting up from `0` to eliminate the need for `e`; `e>0 or-1` is better than `[1,-1][e<0]`. [TIO (140 bytes)](https://tio.run/##nU/RboMwDHzPV1hIU6GNJRKgXYuyx/5Emwe0sTUScytgHdO0b2eJ0/UDJiVwtu/iu8vXeDqTnvcmSZKZZGMcXT7GNBOd6VpKm0wMZmjHAJzJxdUcyC478XlyXQvvjtJr1tALDDsBr@ceJnAEfUNvbeqkW5GkpxzOPapsdz1MD51Fo2oyDeN6QPNNP/WldzQCSQHOTCuK9ewNiXZqn9P9KuHO4ngkRPTfRZ1kS6XmQsJBS1hL2ErwAEt/lQTfrzzaMELNM38KK3RU@La2oroXpRUqFv6HN57iSseG2sSO37C9jzGqw9qwb81WsGIWFlEbXwnHivJ/shAT724K5lUs8qYeObzK/Q2UEKGI0aqbeab9vVuyuuTIIYUf6TJo7S8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>167</s> 163 bytes

```r
function(n,a,l=sum(a^0),u=rep(n,l),v=0)while(!(all(a%in%v))&min(u)){for(i in F+0:(n-sign(n))){x=i%%l+1
v=c(v,a[x]);u[x]=u[x]-1}
print(tail(v,abs(n)));n=a[x];F=i+n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5dT8MwDHzvrzAPZbaaSE02QFDy2j9BQQrVBpEyb@oXk6b@9uJ2fQApti93vpOb6dAzvGqYZ92FEyMrr6Jr@yP6j5xU75r9WchIanA5/XyHuMc79DGiTwOnA9H9MTD2RNfDqcEAgaHM8hdk3YYvySNRLi6kacxMMrgaB@XfLu9U9NLd3LQZk3MTuMPOhzjrn@3iK9jNq0XpQsbjVN5u/XMqeIKr/G@wgNp3uKlY64or3tCYiAW3Cmq0Ch4VPCsQoHdSRoEID4KeFqTtosnbEi0@u/pEtCtlVkqm/rcmGVZSjSGapl8)

I started with a slightly longer solution but then got inspired by [TFeld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38592/tfeld)'s [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/visit-and-exit-an-array/156960#156960) which saved me 3 bytes.

*−4 bytes thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).*

Comment: use `F` instead of `f` to save another 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, <s>112</s> 109 bytes

```
=HQJ@H0K@H1=H.{K=bJ=Y*]0lKW&>J@.MZY0HI._bVrZ+Zb XYNh@YN=b@KN=-Hbp+bd).?Vr+ZbZ XYNh@YN=b@KN=-Hbp+bd))=Z+Nbp"\n
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3DHQJ%40H0K%40H1%3DH.%7BK%3DbJ%3DY%2a%5D0lKW%26>J%40.MZY0HI._bVrZ%2BZb+XYNh%40YN%3Db%40KN%3D-Hbp%2Bbd%29.%3FVr%2BZbZ+XYNh%40YN%3Db%40KN%3D-Hbp%2Bbd%29%29%3DZ%2BNbp"%5Cn&input=2%2C+%5B1%2C+-2%2C+3%2C+-4%2C+5%2C+-6%2C+6%2C+-5%2C+4%2C+-3%2C+2%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%2C+%5B2%2C+6%2C+9%2C+2%2C+-4%2C+-1%2C+3%2C+5%2C+-7%2C+3%2C+-2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A2%2C+%5B2%2C+3%2C+2%5D%0A5%2C+%5B2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A1%2C+%5B2%2C+1%2C+-3%5D%0A2%2C+%5B1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+-3%5D%0A17%2C+%5B1%2C+4%2C+9%5D%0A2%2C+%5B1%2C+-2%2C+3%2C+-4%2C+5%2C+-6%2C+6%2C+-5%2C+4%2C+-3%2C+2%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A4%2C+%5B1%2C+-2%2C+3%2C+-4%2C+5%2C+-6%2C+6%2C+-5%2C+4%2C+-3%2C+2%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A3%2C+%5B-1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+10%2C+11%2C+12%2C+13%5D%0A5%2C+%5B5%2C+2%2C+-3%2C+7%2C+-3%2C+2%2C+-4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%5D%0A2%2C+%5B7%2C+24%2C+11%5D&debug=0)

This is just a translation of [TFeld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38592/tfeld)['s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/visit-and-exit-an-array/156960#156960). Could probably be golfed far better by someone with a better understanding of Pyth, but I figured I might as well share this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 188 bytes

```javascript
(n,l)=>{for(N=l.length,b=l.map(_=>0),o=[],u=l,e=n,p=0,O=[];!o[n]*u[0];p+=j-s,e=j,O.push(g))for(s=e<0?-1:1,g=[],i=0;i<e*s;p+=s)g[i++]=j=l[p=(p%N+N)%N],o[++b[p]]=u=u.filter(k=>k-j);return O}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVJbb5swFH7Pr3AjVcLFRkCg3ZY60173QB76iKwpTQwldTHCMK2q8tszXzBZaKtNWqUQjv1dzsex95ufG7ltq6bDtdixY0GOXo04JKuXQrReRnjAWV12D@helU@bxvtBViFEguQU9YQjRmrUkBCt1cbyQuQ1verzkC4bn@yxVPAerYOmlw9eCaG2lITdhl9x9CVCpTapSLisbtmV1BIJy7zyfUr2hOcN8ZrLzM/gZUaRyH3/Pm8oJT3pg6LiHWu9R7J6xHu4bFnXtzVYH44dkx0gQH0D4AiwXw0EZAVeZgAItf2tbTfPQdGKJ68wFAgVUhXA@363zgLZtVVdVsWzJ@AFIZM9bQa1EwBbUUvBWcBF6c1Ny2JTcbaboxpNVLbFRCL6ruk7AOboVd832Kox23ba/a1Ein8AjEsG3ssm@@2Wsd2HxTvMDjNt7C0QyGMErhH4jIAqcKKeCAG1n6rqxlQ4Npj6LajiOwG12thwXptoGCcDyTJiSqHtG5@2neViBNMRTEZQ1UMCx4osS73wEOvMPTJQPKJ6bcLQATwZ3didZPgmVxuDfyqmjbFNrOegp3htZoNTI8F2FNjmc6msaoym36Np8n@mg4qOM4nc6Uz6ub/3cui7gsex2hNJTQo1wE92GKF6NEUfjJ27U@iFFhjPM5qLYwWnvb90Orsu6XDUhuGmkRhh4q7RhDPczHSA/9SdnacC4kTnNSZmZaSJ/YYR/pBSdT7@Bg) Comes with a header/footer that run the test cases.

Works somewhat like TFeld's Python answer, but ended up slightly longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), `-a` <s>123</s> <s>120</s> <s>116</s> <s>115</s> 114 bytes

This has the slight blemish that it prints an extra space at the start of each line

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -a
@;{@F}=$,=$";say$e!~/-?/,map$U{$z}=$S[++$s[$%]]=$e=$F[$%=($&.1+$%)%@F],($%+=$&.~-$')x($' or$@.=<>)until@S>$@|%U~~%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYm9DoIwFEZ3n@JqbgVSWvkRjcFiJzYnwkQYGBhIEAhgoqJ9dGvNN5yT8w312EZay3iR6UegK3ATT9UT67XascvOvVUD5gu@zJcVlOJUIClLgbXA1Kiwcct9isQhMi1dGwkVpiiGlvOw0YJ@RMnFOXHu3dy0MktQvkmuFNE6gAOcIAC2B@ZDCBGwowEL4L9wFX77YW76btKs0uwacd/j3g8)